# FCM category issue in IOS (React Native)

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

In our React Native, we're trying to implement Notifee for creating notification categories, and we pass the category id to FCM to enable action buttons in FCM notifications.

However, we're encountering an issue specific to iOS where tapping on the action buttons in the notifications doesn't launch the app.
Instead, the specified function associated with the action button is executed in the background (e.g., redirecting the user to a specific screen).

FYI, We're using Notifee version 7.7.1 and React Native version 0.71.
Are there any fixes or workarounds that can be implemented to address this issue?

[Code Snapshot for category creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeCFw.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.